# Running tox with C extension module

Tags: python, tox

I am a newbie to tox. I have a python package that has a C extension module written for python2.7. The web told me that I need to use "tox --wheel" for this case. However, I couldn't get "tox --wheel" to locate my C source code. Can someone lend me a hand?

My module can compile fine with python setup.py build. However, gcc in "tox --wheel" complains that my C source code couldn't be found. What config is missing? Thanks a lot in advance!

My setup.py looks like this:

```py
import os
del os.link
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

module1 = Extension('_HelloWorld_py',
                    sources = ['HelloWorld.c'],
                    include_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/'],
                    extra_compile_args = ['-std=c99','-Wno-error=vla'])

setup (name = 'HelloWorld',
       version = '0.1',
       description = 'Hello World',
       package_data={'': ['*.h', '*.c']},
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

My tox.ini looks like this:

```py
[tox]
envlist =
  py27

[testenv]
wheel=true
basepython=py27: python2.7
deps=
  pytest
  numpy
changedir={envdir}
commands=
  {envpython} {toxinidir}/runtests.py --mode=full {posargs:}
```

Error message looks like this:

```py
py27 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='2083224069'
py27 run-test: commands[1] | /home/user/helloworld-release/.tox/py27/bin/python /home/user/helloworld-release/setup.py bdist_wheel
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building '_HelloWorld_py' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c HelloWorld.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/HelloWorld.o -std=c99 -Wno-error=vla
gcc: error: HelloWorld.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/user/helloworld-release/.tox/py27/bin/python /home/user/helloworld-release/setup.py bdist_wheel (exited with code 1)
ERROR: No distributions found in the dist directory found. Please check setup.py, e.g with:
     python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Comment: You used `python setup.py build` directly, which (AFAIK) is not the same as `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, have you tried running that directly?

Comment: "python setup.py bdist_wheel" worked also. Removing "changedir={envdir}" as suggested by hoefling solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `changedir={envdir}`. It changes the current directory to `.tox/py27`, so `hello.c` in the setup script will resolve to a nonexistent `.tox/py27/hello.c`.

If you need to keep the working directory changed, you can use absolute paths in the setup script:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages


rootdir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))
module1 = Extension('_HelloWorld_py',
                    sources = [os.path.join(rootdir, 'HelloWorld.c')],
                    ...)

setup(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Not expecting a quick reply for such a non-mainstream question.

Comment: Glad I could help!